# WordPress taxonomy in CPT URL

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

I've created a CPT with a taxonomy, the current URL for the detail page is `/items/test` where "test" is the name of the CPT item. Now I've set an taxonomy using ACF (so I can limit it to a single taxonomy) although it might as well have been set natively with the WordPress sidebar.

Now I want the URL to change the URL to something like this `/items/waterproof/test` where "test" is still the item name and "waterproof" is the selected taxonomy, I figure I have to use rewrite for this but I've been trying for a while and can't seem figure it out

Any suggestions?

Comment: Please check https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/94817/add-category-base-to-url-in-custom-post-type-taxonomy

Comment: And here is the complete guide https://www.ibenic.com/custom-wordpress-rewrite-rule-combine-taxonomy-post-type/ Also a discussion on wordpress.org https://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-add-custom-taxonomy-in-custom-post-type-permalink/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/328360) answer from a diffrent StackOverflow post, thanks to @Chengmin for leaving this suggestion! Wish I'd found it myself ;)

```
CustomPostTypeHelper::registerPostType(\Entity\Product::POST_TYPE_NAME, [
    'labels' => [
        'name' => 'Producten',
        'singular_name' => 'Product',
        'all_items' => 'Alle producten',
        'edit_item' => 'Product bewerken',
        'add_new' => 'Nieuw Product',
        'add_new_item' => 'Product toevoegen'
    ],
    'publicly_queryable' => true,
    'exclude_from_search' => false,
    'show_ui' => true,
    'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
    'show_in_menu' => true,
    'show_in_admin_bar' => true,
    'public' => true,
    'has_archive' => true,
    'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-products',
    'supports' => [
        'title',
        'editor'
    ],
    'rewrite' => [
        'slug' => 'verkoop/%taxonomy%'
    ]
]);
```

This is my CPT, it should we noted that I have wrapped the `register_post_type` function in a custom function, but I still use the same arguments so just focus on that. The relevant information is the rewrite value which I changed to `verkoop/%taxononmy%` where "verkoop" is the fixed prefix and "%taxonomy%" being (you guessed it) the taxonomy I want embedded in the URL.

```
function productLink($link, $id = 0)
{
  $post = get_post($id);

  if (is_object($post)) {
      $terms = wp_get_object_terms($post->ID, 'category_product_category');
      if ($terms) return str_replace( '%taxonomy%', $terms[0]->slug, $link );
  }

  return $link;
}

add_filter('post_type_link', 'productLink', 1, 3);
```

This is the PHP used to generate the URL when creating or editing an instance of the CPT. As you can see in the snippet: my taxonomy is named "category_product_category"

```
function producteRewrite()  
{ 
  add_rewrite_rule( 
      '^verkoop/(.*)/(.*)/?$', 
      'index.php?post_type=product&name=$matches[2]', 
      'top' 
  ); 
} 
 
add_action('init', 'producteRewrite');
```

And last but not least, this is the rewrite rule to redirect the user to the correct detail page, I don't actually query based on the taxonomy and just use the post slug. My client only wanted this for SEO (and personal preference) so I don't care about filtering based on taxonomy

Comment: Instead of posting just a link, I suggest you to include the actual code that *you* used - there ought to be at least some parts you changed, right?

Comment: That's fair, I've updated my answer :) @SallyCJ

Comment: Thank you, now your answer looks like good answer. :) But if I may comment on a few things: 1) If `\Entity\Product::POST_TYPE_NAME` is `product`, I wonder why do you need to add the custom rewrite rule because your CPT's rewrite slug is already in the form of `verkoop/<category slug>/<post slug>`, so WordPress would naturally use that structure in the post permalink, which means the user will indeed be sent to `example.com/verkoop/sample-category/sample-post` and WordPress will query the `sample-post` without you having to set the custom rewrite rule.

Comment: And 2) The second parameter for the [`post_type_link` hook](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/post_type_link/) is actually `$post` which is a `WP_Post` instance, so you should use the same name in your callback (`productLink()`).